# Merge two datasets using Node/JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, merge

I'm struggling with merging two datasets. What I need is to create a new array of arrays containing a merge of the two below datasets. The first dataset overwrites the second if there is a match of vehicle type (i.e. Car)

Dataset A - to be merged into Dataset B

```
[ [ 'Cars', '', 'description here', 'true', '3' ],
  [ 'Trucks', '', 'desc', 'true', '3' ],
  [ 'Boats', '', 'desc', 'true', '3' ] ]
```

Dataset B

```
[ { level: '3',
    description: 'description here',
    name: 'Cars',
    availableForUse: false },
  { level: '3',
    description: 'desc',
    name: 'Trucks',
    availableForUse: false },
  { level: '3',
    description: 'desc',
    name: 'Boats',
    availableForUse: false },
  { level: '3',
    description: 'desc',
    name: 'Trains',
    availableForUse: false } ]
```

What I've done so far is to iterate over dataset B then search dataset A for a match - if there is a match then the data from dataset A should make it into the new array and the same data from dataset B should be omitted.

Here is my code so far which is not giving me this outcome. With this code I'm seeing duplicates of Cars.

```
for(var i = 0; i < datasetB.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < datasetA.length; j++) {
        if (datasetB[i].name == datasetA[j][0]) {
            recordArray.push(datasetA[j][0], datasetA[j][1], datasetB[i].description, datasetA[j][3]);
            servicesCollectionArray.push(recordArray);
            datasetA.splice(j, 1);
            recordArray = [];
            if (datasetA.length < 1) {
                break;
            }

        }
        if (datasetB[i].name != datasetA[j][0]) {
            recordArray.push(datasetB[i].name, "", datasetB[i].description, "false");
            servicesCollectionArray.push(recordArray);
            recordArray = [];
        }
    }
}
```

Heres what I'm getting with this code:

```
[ [ 'Cars', '', 'description here', 'true' ],
  [ 'Cars', '', 'description here', 'false' ],
  [ 'Cars', '', 'description here', 'false' ],
  [ 'Trucks', '', 'desc', 'true' ],
  [ 'Trucks', '', 'desc', 'false' ],
  [ 'Boats', '', 'desc', 'true' ] ]
```

Here's what I want:

```
[ [ 'Cars', '', 'description here', 'true' ],
  [ 'Trucks', '', 'desc', 'true' ],
  [ 'Boats', '', 'desc', 'true' ],
  [ 'Trains', '', 'desc', 'false' ] ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are two problems here.. One of merging the datasets & another of making the result unique.

So the best way would be to take a third bucket. And while we pick & drop the required elements into it, just check for it's existence as well.

Say d1 & d2 are your arrays. Then let's take a temporary object t to filter out. This allows us to quickly check while pushing in.

Since as per your requirement d1 has more preference, we iterate it through first.

Finally, push everything into a result array:

```
var t = {}, result = [];

d1.forEach(function (d) { if(!t[d[0]]) t[d[0]] = [d[0],d[2],d[3]]; });
d2.forEach(function (d) { if(!t[d.name]) t[d.name] = [d.name,d.description,d.availableForUse]; });

for(var i in t) result.push(t[i]);

// result holds your answer
```